# Serving untouched data through Mapbox's static API

Tags: mapbox

I would like to use Mapbox's static API to serve some PNG images in which I have encoded georeferenced data, so that I can do some JavaScript data manipulation on the client side (I don't want to show these images). My problem is that this data cannot be changed - reprojected or scaled, and I only have it in EPSG:4326, not in EPSG:900913 and not in the resolution of any zoom level.

Is there a way to tell Mapbox to store the raster data in its original form, without changing it, and just serve a rectangular chunk of it centred on a particular location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't do this: Mapbox's API is ESPG:900913-only. The long answer is that if you really want to, you can use [GDAL to represent your ESPG:4326 image as a non-geographic 900913 image](http://www.macwright.org/2012/08/13/images-as-maps.html). This is, to be clear, *the long route* and means that you'll need to do all of the reprojection math to determine the geographical transformation from the original data to the now-fake coordinates.

Comment: I tried to do that and then figured out it was more complicated than I thought it would be, for the reasons you mentioned. I ended up letting Mapbox reproject my data, but by encoding the data coordinates into the red and green colors, and using the blue for the data, I managed to recover the original data (with a zoom level that prevents any loss of information). The data was water flow direction and the result can be checked out here: http://t.co/KS7zdsSCzZ